# How to locate a tap on the screen? X, Y cordinates

Tags: java, android, touch-event

I'm trying to get the location (x, y in pixels) of a tap when tapping on the screen of the device.
here is my code that i found:

```java
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int)event.getX();
    int y = (int)event.getY();
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    }
    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(y);
    return true;
}
```

But it does not fire the event.
where is the problem?

Comment: Look for `I/System.out` - that's what the log level / tag of `System.out.println` should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.out.println is for the classic, desktop console.
Try using the Log output. It will be presented in LogCat. You can choose among different types of logs - verbose, info, debug, warn and error. Useful syntax may look like (although it's not following android's Log convention):

```
String xstr = Integer.toString(x);
Log.d("X location: ", xstr);
```

Also take a look [here to learn more about android logs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html).